# React mapping menu from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, web-applications, jsx

I have a scrolling menu items, and the titles of each item is hardcoded into a const, along side with the id

```
const list = [
  { name: "category1", id: 0 },
  { name: "category2", id: 1 },
  { name: "category3", id: 2 },
  { name: "category4", id: 3 },
  { name: "category5", id: 4 },
  { name: "category6", id: 5 },
  { name: "category7", id: 6 },
  { name: "category8", id: 7 }
];
```

I have a json file that contains the category name for each child:

```
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "category": "category1",
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "ernesto",
        "last": "roman"
      },
      "email": "ernesto.roman@example.com",
      "id": {
        "name": "DNI",
        "value": "73164596-W"
      },
      "picture": {
        "large": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/73.jpg",
        "medium": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/men/73.jpg",
        "thumbnail": "https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/73.jpg"
      }
    },
    {
      "category": "category2",
      "name": {
        "title": "mr",
        "first": "adalbert",
        "last": "bausch"
      },
      "email": "adalbert.bausch@example.com",
      "id": {
        "name": "",
        "value": null
      } etc....
```

I want to show these categories `"category": "category1"`, as the titles of my menu, I now that I need to start stateless and add them from the JSON, the fetching part from the JSON is done locally in componentDidMount, but I am not sure how can I map them into appearing as menu names to make the menu dynamic, I basically want the same output but from the json not hardcoded. here is a sandbox snippet, would appreciate the help.

https://codesandbox.io/s/2prw4j729p?fontsize=14&moduleview=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the JSON output to an object like `list` with a `map` function from the results and then set is as `MenuItems` on the state, which is what you pass to the function on `render()`. Like that.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ScrollMenu from "react-horizontal-scrolling-menu";
import "./menu.css";

// One item component
// selected prop will be passed
const MenuItem = ({ text, selected }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="menu-item">{text}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

// All items component
// Important! add unique key
export const Menu = list =>
  list.map(el => {
    const { name, id } = el;
    return <MenuItem text={name} key={id} />;
  });

const Arrow = ({ text, className }) => {
  return <div className={className}>{text}</div>;
};

export class Menucat extends Component {
  state = {
    selected: "0",
    MenuItems: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("menu.json")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        const items = result.results.map((el, idx) => {
          return { name: el.category, id: idx };
         });
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          MenuItems: items
        });
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { selected, MenuItems } = this.state;
    // Create menu from items
    const menu = Menu(MenuItems, selected);

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ScrollMenu
          data={menu}
          selected={selected}
          onSelect={this.onSelect}
          alignCenter={true}
          tabindex="0"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Menucat;
```

Cheers!

Comment: what if the menu.json have sub-category as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't have to hard code your category list at all. In your `componentDidMount()` fetch the json and group the results into separate categories like this:

```
const json = {
    "results": [
        {
            category: "category1",
            name: "Fred"
        },
        {
            category: "category1",
            name: "Teddy"
        },
        {
            category: "category2",
            name: "Gilbert"
        },
        {
            category: "category3",
            name: "Foxy"
        },
    ]
}
const grouped = json.results.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(cur.category)) {
        acc[cur.category] = []
    }
    acc[cur.category].push(cur)
    return acc;
}, { })

// parent object now has 3 properties, namely category1, category2 and category3
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped, null, 4))

// each of these properties is an array of bjects of same category
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped.category1, null, 4))
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped.category2, null, 4))
console.log(JSON.stringify(grouped.category3, null, 4))
```

Note that this json has 4 objects in result array, 2 of cat1, and 1 of cat 2 and cat3. You can run this code in a separate file to see how it works. Ofcourse you will be fetching the json object from server. I just set it for demonstration.

Then set teh state:
`this.setState({ grouped })`

Then in `render()` you only show the categories that have items like:

```
const menuBarButtons = Object.keys(this.state.grouped).map((category) => {
    /* your jsx here */
    return <MenuItem text={category} key={category} onClick={this.onClick} blah={blah}/>
    /* or something , it's up to you */
})
```

I'm assuming you're showing the items based on the currently selected category `this.state.selected`. So after you have rendered your menu, you would do something like:

```
const selectedCatItems = this.state.grouped[this.state.selected].map((item) => {
    return <YourItem name={item.name} key={item.id} blah={blah} />
})
```

Then render it:

```
return (
    <div className="app">
        <MenuBar blah={blah}>
            {menuBarButtons}
        </Menubar>
        <div for your item showing area>
            {selectedCatItems}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Also, don't forget to change your `onClick()` so that it sets `this.state.selected` state properly. I believe you can figure that out yourself.

Hope it helps.

PS: I didn't write a whole copy/paste solution to your problem simply because I'm reluctant to read and understand your UI details and the whole component to component data passing details..